# File Manager and Assets Sub Folders

Tags: expresso-store, assets, file-manager

I am having an issue with Assets sub folders and Expression Engine File Manager.

I have a folder called photos. In assets i create sub folders more for organisation purposes as having lots of images in the same folder will be hard to maintain at a later date as file count increases.

The problem is when moving files into these folders. Files are no longer shown in File Manager. Because of this I am having issues with expresso store download tag.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Keeping the files in the photos folder everything is fine even using assets. It is only when organising the files do I have problems.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expression Engine, Assets, ExpressoStore](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/26975/expression-engine-assets-expressostore)

Answer (score 0):

The EE File Manager can't see inside subfolders - only the top-level folder. In this respect, Assets and the File Manager don't play well together.

I see from the [Store docs](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/download_tag.html) that they indeed need the file to be indexed by the File Manager, so there's a feature request to be made to DevDemon there.

But maybe an add-on like [Link Vault](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/link-vault) would help here, in place of the Store Download tag?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. On a different note. I found that placing .htaccess restrictions on the folder with the hi-resolution images prevented downloading them by changing the url and accessing the file this way (hot linking). But after a successful purchases using expressoStore and showing the download tag you are able to download the file successfully with an order hash. Is this a good enough measure in protecting the files? Or do I need to take a different approach to this? It seems good enough but perhaps i am missing something important on a hacking perspective. Any tips would be great.