# Expression Engine, Assets, ExpressoStore

Tags: expresso-store, assets

I have almost finished a white label version of a photography download
e-commerce site.

I have now hit a brick wall. If I keep all of my photos in the root folder
say 'photos' everything is fine. But introducing sub folders into the mix is a
no go area. Apparently Expression Engines File Manager
does not allow sub folder indexing and this is causing a problem with
Expresso Store download tag.

Is there absolutely no way I can get around this problem with the assets
plugin?

I can see initially files will be fine in one folder. But sooner or later
this is going to be very difficult to manage and this is where sub folders
come to the rescue.

I would really like to know if there is a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Store Download tag (`{exp:store:download}`) you can only use what the default EE File Manager can see/use. So you would not be able to use subfolders.

Having said that you don't have to use the Store download tags to allow users to download the files after the purchase. You could use a third-party solution such [Link Vault](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/link-vault) to secure your downloads folder and files. Link Vault works with Assets (I believe only if you are using the fieldtype tags `{your_assets_field:url}`) so you would be able to have subfolders to help with maintaining your downloads folder.

Comment: Thanks Justin I will have a look at this and see how it works out. ;)

Comment: Hi Justin this is working out very nice indeed. A quick question. I am also using Link Vault for showing the preview photos, so a user could not guess where the large photo is based off the url. The url is encrypted. Am I approaching this the correct way?

Comment: It is going to add a bit of overhead to your template depending on how many fields you have but I dont see it being a problem.